# Syntax in php variable with ' and "

Tags: php, string, variables, shortcode

In php, I have a variable with shortcodes using atts:

```
$ret = '<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=[slshar text="title"]&url=[slshar text="url"]">Link</a>';
```

I don't know how to manage ' and " in this variable in shortcodes for "title" and "url".
I tried: \"title\" => does not work

[slshar text="title"] = "Titre du post 2"  = "Titre du post 2"
[slshar text="url"]   = "slug of post 2"' = "https;//pur-plan.com/post2"
The result must be : 
`$ret = '<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="Titre du post"&url="https;//pur-plan.com/post2">Link</a>;`
I tested the shorcode: every thing is ok and the values returned are ok. 
With this syntax, the URL returned is truncated after "?text=". THis is normal because of the "
I hope my explanations are enough for you to help me.
Can you, please, help me to fix that.
Regards,
Bruno

Comment: What is held in your text and url variables on the server side?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Are those short codes supposed to be replaced by actual values, or are you trying to transport those shortcodes as URL parameters? If the former: where/when/how are you trying to replace them? If the latter: you need to URL-encode those values since you're trying to transport them in a URL, and then HTML-encode the entire URL since you're trying to put it into HTML.

Comment: You must turn the shortcodes into values separately from the URL, e.g.: `$title = '[slshar text="title"]; $title = shortcode_magic($title);` Then *URL-encode* it, then put it into the URL.

Comment: How `[slshar text="title"]` get changed to `Titre du post` how do these 2 strings relate?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.
I solved the problem with the belowed solution and some css to design the buttons.
If you customize a loop in an archive (with Elementor Custom Skin for exemple), this code displays link to share posts on twitter and facebook.

```
add_shortcode( 'social-sharing-inf', function ( $atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'inf'   => '',
    ), $atts));
    global $post;
    switch ( $inf ) {
        case 'twitter' :
            $ret  = '<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=';
            $ret .= 'PUR-PLAN.com vous propose la bonne affaire suivante :%0D' . $post->post_title .'%0DCliquez sur le lien suivant pour y accéder :';
            $ret .= '&url=https://pur-plan.com/' . $post->post_name;
            $ret .= '" onclick="window.open(this.href, \'twitterwindow\',\'left=20,top=20,width=600,height=300,toolbar=0,resizable=1\'); return false;" ';
            $ret .= 'class="share-button-twitter-a"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Twitter</a>';
        break;
        case 'facebook' :
            $ret  = '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://pur-plan.com/' . $post->post_name;
            $ret .= '" onclick="window.open(this.href, \'facebookwindow\',\'left=20,top=20,width=600,height=700,toolbar=0,resizable=1\'); return false;" ';
            $ret .= 'class="share-button-facebook-a"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>facebook </a>';
        break;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return "$ret";
});
```

and I call with the shortcode: [social-sharing-inf inf="twitter"] and [social-sharing-inf inf="facebook"]
Certainely, this code could be optimized but it works good.
If you have any improvements, I'll take it!